# Laurent-series expansion of $\frac{1}{(e^z-1)^2}$ about $z=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, taylor-expansion, laurent-series

I am studying for exams in complex analysis and taking a look at past papers. This comes up often or an integral of the given function along a certain curve, which is actually the same thing since the residue is all one needs.

Googling [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006615/laurent-series-expansion-of-1-ez-1) came up but I seem to be unable to go from there.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Jack thank you for the title edit. Excuse me for messing it up.

Answer (score 2):

We may define [Bernoulli numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_number) through:
$$ \frac{z}{e^{z}-1}=\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{z^n}{n!}\,B_n.\tag{1} $$
It follows that:
$$ \frac{1}{e^{z}-1}=\sum_{n\geq -1}\frac{z^{n}}{(n+1)!}\,B_{n+1},\tag{2} $$
$$ \frac{-e^z}{(e^{z}-1)^2}=\sum_{n\geq -2}\frac{(n+1)\,z^{n}}{(n+2)!}\,B_{n+2},\tag{3} $$
hence the Laurent expansion of our function follows from considering the opposite of the sum between $(2)$ and $(3)$. $(3)$ follows from $(2)$ by differentiation with respect to $z$.