# What kind of series is the function $\frac{x}{e^x-1}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series

[How to expand the series $\dfrac{1}{e^x-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420982/how-to-expand-the-series-dfrac1ex-1/3421012?noredirect=1#comment7035566_3421012)

[Series expansion for $f(x)=\frac{x}{e^x-1}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3420676/series-expansion-for-fx-fracxex-1?noredirect=1#comment7035393_3420676)

In these topics, I have asked for a way to develop the function $\dfrac{x}{e^x-1}$ into series. I won't do that here.
From what I see, this function should not have a Maclaurin series (centered at 0) since the function and its higher derivative remain undefined when x=0. Then what is the name for the series derived from the topics that I mention above. Is it a Laurent series or Puisseux series?

Comment: Technically $f(x) = x/ (e^x - 1)$ is not defined at $x=0$, but the limit exist as $x \rightarrow 0$, so it is a removable discontinuity.  If you define a new function $g(x) = x/(e^x-1)$ for $x \neq 0$, and $g(0) = 1$, then the function has a Maclaurin series.

Answer (score 2):

The function itself is not a series, of any kind. A series is one way to represent a function.

I think the term you're looking for is Laurent series. This is the generalisation of Maclaurin series that allows for negative integer exponents.

Puisseux series allow for *fractional* exponents as well. That is not what these examples use, so while the term may technically be applicable (I don't know much about them personally), it's not what I would call it.

Comment: But can I form a Laurent series to represent a function when it is not defined at 0?

Comment: Yes. That's the point. Laurent series, in addition to terms like $x^2$ and $x^{739}$ also has terms like $\frac1x$ and $\frac1{x^{1337}}$. Those are not defined at $0$, but they are defined _around_ $0$.

Answer (score 0):

The Bernoulli numbers $B_n$ can be generated by
\begin{equation*}
\frac{z}{e^z-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n\frac{z^n}{n!}=1-\frac{z}2+\sum_{n=1}^\infty B_{2n}\frac{z^{2n}}{(2n)!}, \quad \vert z\vert<2\pi.
\end{equation*}
Since the function
$
\frac{x}{e^x-1}-1+\frac{x}2
$
is even in $x\in\mathbb{R}$, all the Bernoulli numbers $B_{2n+1}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$ equal $0$.

1. Feng Qi, *A double inequality for the ratio of two non-zero neighbouring Bernoulli numbers*, Journal of Computational and Applied Mathematics **351** (2019), 1--5; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.cam.2018.10.049.