# Classifying of isolated singularities

Tags: singularity

I want to find out, which singualrities $f(z)=\frac{z}{e^z+1}$ have?

$e^z+1=0 \Leftrightarrow z_k=(2k+1)i \pi $

But how can I find out, of which type these singualrities are?

Comment: $(2k+1)\pi $ is a zero of order 1 in $e^z+1$ and it is not a root of $z$ . So each of these is a pole of order $1$

Comment: I see:) The Laurent- series is too difficult to compute?

Comment: u dont need to compute it eplicitly

Answer (score 1):

The numerator plays no role in this matter. Just compute the Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+e^z}$ and determine if the number of terms with negative index is finite (in this case the singularity is a pole) or infinite (in this case it is an essential singularity). You can search for inspiration in [This link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1006615/laurent-series-expansion-of-1-ez-1)

Comment: Can you maybe explain, how he got from the first line to the second: $$\frac{1}{e^z-1} = 1/z - P(z)/z + P(z)^2/z - P(z)^3/z + ...  \\
= 1/z - 1/2  - z/3! + z/(2!)^2 - z^2/4! + 2z^2/(2!\cdot 3!) - z^2/(2!)^3 + O(z^3) \\$$