# Why is the value of the coefficient $a_0=-1/2$ in this product of two series?

Tags: proof-explanation

I've read this [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3394367/637375) and know why $a_{-1}=1$ but I really don't get how $a_0=-\frac{1}{2}$.

Here is the equation in question:
$$\left(\sum_{n\ge0}a_{n-1}z^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge0}\frac{z^n}{(n+1)!}\right)=1.$$
I can only see that $a_{-1}\frac{z^2}{6}+a_0z\cdot \frac{z}{2}+a_1z^2 = 0$.

Comment: Please, use descriptive titles. "Why is $a_0=−1/2$?" says nothing about the subject of the question.

Comment: @jjagmath What would you write as title? As it relates to another question I'm not sure what to add

Comment: How about something like "the value of a coefficient in the product of two series" or something like that?

Comment: @jjagmath sounds good. I've adapted the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The coefficient of $z$ on the left side is $\frac {a_{-1}} {2!}+a_0$ and this must be $0$. This gives $a_0=-\frac 1  2$.

Comment: Ah okay. So I'm looking at $z$ instead of $z^2$. Oops.